# How to annotate a function with a generic return value in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Given a function that returns a factory, how can I annotate the function/factory so that it contains the correct type definitions?

Here's my example:

```
class item<T> {
  constructor(a: T) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  a: T
}

function generate(c) {
  return function a(a) {
    return new c(a);
  }
}

const factory = generate(item); // I want this to always be annotated as <T> (a: T) => item<T>

const instance = factory('string'); // instance should now be of type item<string>
```

Is this possible in typescript or should I suggest it as a new feature?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to mutate the constructor signature to a function signature while keeping the generic type parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non generic classes we can in 3.0 use [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) and `InstanceType` to map the constructor to a similar function.

For generic classes unfortunately there is no way to preserve the type argument when mapping. The only solution is to add a field to the class that will tell `generate` what the result type should be. This can be done using interface-class merging so the original class does not know about generate.

A possible solution using both approaches (automatic where possible, manual where necessary) could look something like this:

```
class item<T> {
    constructor(a: T) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    a: T
}

const generateResult = Symbol.for("generate")
interface item<T> {
    [generateResult] : <T>(a: T) => item<T>    
}

type d = item<any>[typeof generateResult]

type SupportsGeneration<R> =  { [generateResult] : R }
type ConstructorArguments<T> = T extends new (...a:infer A ) => any ? A : [];


function generate<T extends { new (...a:any[]) : SupportsGeneration<any> }>(c:T) :  InstanceType<T> extends SupportsGeneration<infer R> ? R: never
function generate<T extends new (...a:any[]) => any>(c:T) :  (a: ConstructorArguments<T>) => InstanceType<T>
function generate(c: new (...a: any[]) => any) : any {
    return function a(...a: any[]) {
        return new c(...a);
    }
}

const factory = generate(item); 

const instance = factory('string');
```

Comment: @cwohlman it's workaround ... its not pretty but it can be useful :)

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't solve my actual problem, I guess I oversimplified my question, my actual case involves returning nested functions each of which takes a single argument and which finally return the constructed object, e.g. `generate(Item)('arg1')('arg2')`. If I get time I'll write it up as a separate question & link it here.

Comment: @cwohlman If `Item` is not a generic type, I think that can actually be done in a type safe way using conditional types, but I would have to see the actual code.

Comment: `Item` is very definitely generic, and the second type argument is guaranteed to be unknown at the time of calling `generate(Item)`.

Comment: @cwohlman still post it if you get a chance seems like an interesting question someone is bound to have an interesting solution ;)

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931628/how-to-annotate-nested-functions-with-generic-type-arguments

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible to achieve desired effect since v3.4:

```js
class item<T> {
  constructor(a: T) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  a: T
}

function generate<Arg, Result>(c: new (arg: Arg) => Result) {
  return function a(a: Arg) {
    return new c(a);
  }
}

const factory = generate(item); // I want this to always be annotated as <T> (a: T) => item<T>
const instance = factory('string'); // instance should now be of type item<string>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code)