# How to annotate nested functions with generic type arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

Given a function that returns a factory, how can I annotate the function/factory so that it contains the correct type definitions?

Here's my example:

```
class item<TA, TB> {
  constructor(a: TA, b: TB) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  a: T
}

function generate(c) {
  return function a(a) {
    return function b(b) {
      return new c(a, b);
    }
  }
}

const factory = generate(item); // I want this to always be annotated as <TA, TB> (a: TA) => (b: TB) => item<TA, TB>

const partial = factory('string'); // instance should now be of type <TB> (b: TB) => item<string, TB>

const instance = partial('string'); // instance should now be of type item<string, string>
```

Is this possible in typescript or should I suggest it as a new feature?

Comment: I think a similar (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897586/how-to-annotate-a-function-with-a-generic-return-value-in-typescript) workaround can work, but there is no automatic solution as far as I can see

Comment: If I understand correctly that `c` is a constructor of a generic type, this seems to require [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which TypeScript doesn't currently support.